# ¿Cómo ejecutar dos comandos de CMD?

Tags: c#, windows, cmd

Tengo el problema de que requiero ejecutar dos lineas de CMD diferentes, pero no lo he logrado, únicamente me ejecuta esta primer linea.

```
        var info = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("CMD.exe", @"/c  icacls C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test /grant juan:(OI)(CI)(W,WDAC,GW,WD,WEA,WA,RC,RX)");
        info.Verb = "open";
        info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        info.UseShellExecute = false;  
        System.Diagnostics.Process procesito = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        procesito.StartInfo = info;
        procesito.Start();
        string resultado = procesito.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        Console.Write(resultado);
```

He intentado crear una variable diferente con la segunda linea que quiero ejecutar y crear otra instancia así:

```
        var otra= new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("CMD.exe", @"/c  icacls C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test /reset /T");
        otra.Verb = "open";
        otra.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        otra.UseShellExecute = false;  
        System.Diagnostics.Process x= new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        x.StartInfo = info;
        x.Start();
        string resultadox = x.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        Console.Write(resultadox);
```

Pero no me funciona cuando llega a la parte donde ejecuta la segunda linea me manda un error de seguridad. ¿Cómo puedo ejecutar dos instancias de este tipo? ó ¿Cómo podría utilizar la misma instancia pero cambiarle la linea de CMD que quiero ejecutar?

**UPDATE**
Error:

> Error de solicitud de permiso de tipo
>   'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Comment: Sería de gran ayuda sí mostraras cual es el error de seguridad que te está arrojando, pues hay muchas posibilidades por las cuales puede estar dando error, ayudaría mucho si agregas este detalle

Comment: Lo siento se me paso, he agregado el error.

Comment: de casualidad, tu Visual Studio fue abierto con permisos de administrador?

Comment: Así es, con permisos de administrador.

Comment: Intenta ejecutar los dos comandos desde el CMD normalmente, a ver si desde ahí te da algún inconveniente, pues me parece que debe ser un error de permisos

Comment: He ejecutado ambos en el CMD y ejecutan sin problema, he ejecutado cada uno por separado desde Visual Studio y trabajan sin problema el problema esta cuando intento ejecutar uno detrás de otro.

Comment: Podrías ejecutar el proceso, pero con otra carpeta que no sea el IIS, alguna que crees en el escritorio o así, y decirnos cual es el resultado?

Comment: El resultado es el mismo con carpetas con todos los permisos, el error recae al tratar de ejecutar las dos lineas aunque la carpeta tenga todos los permisos.

Answer (score 1):

Totalmente me suena a un problema de permisos a la hora de tener acceso a la carpeta y otros archivos y subcarpetas que están dentro de la dirección que pones ahí. Al yo ejecutar tu código, no me dio ningún error, pero al buscar un poco de información y mirar un poco tu código creo que te puedo dar algunas recomendaciones.

Primero que todo te aconsejo que visites el siguiente [link](http://csharptest.net/321/how-to-use-systemdiagnosticsprocess-correctly/index.html) que trata el como usar correctamente System.Diagnostics.Process.

Segundo, en tu código, veo que tanto para `procesito` como para `x` se le está asignando a la propiedad `StartInfo` la variable `info`.

Tercero, tanto para `procesito` como para `x` poner la propiedad `EnableRaisingEvents = true`.

Cuarto, Después de ejecutar `procesito.Start();`, para esperar que se termine de ejecutar el proceso, ponerlo en espera hasta que se cierre por medio de la instrucción:

```
while(!procesito.HasExited)
{}; //espera a que el proceso termine
while (!procesito.WaitForExit(1000));
string resultado = procesito.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
Console.Write(resultado);
procesito.Close();
//retomar el flujo normal
```

Espero esto te ayude o por lo menos te de una guía de por donde buscar para resolver tu problema.

Comment: Verificare la información, y te comento. Gracias.

Comment: Perfecto, avísame como te fue